# React invalid hook Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I have an error in React. It's a newly initiated project with just a few components.
The error is referenced to both the useState() and to useEffect().

Error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:14906)
    at useState (react.development.js:1508)
    at IndexPage (IndexPage.js:9)
    at Route.js:55
    at updateContextConsumer (react-dom.development.js:18747)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19114)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:8)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (const.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

And

```
The above error occurred in the <Router.Consumer> component:

    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37878:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:38080:29)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37513:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37133:35)
    at App
```

Both react and react-dom is the same version (^17.0.1)

[image]

The component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import General from '../generalInfo/General'
import Axios from 'axios'

import {MAIN_URL} from '../../utils/const.js'

const IndexPage = () => {

    const [generalInfo, setGeneralInfo] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getGeneral();
    }, [])

    const getGeneral = () => {
        console.log("Getting general");
        Axios.get(MAIN_URL + "/general", {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'authorized', 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).then(response => {
            if(response.status === 404){
                console.log("Not Found");
                //Implement error handling
            }else{
                setGeneralInfo(response.data);
            }
        })
    }


    return (
        <div id = "locationBG">
            <main className="container mt-3" itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Person">
                <article className="row">
                    /*Start of left column*/
                    <section class="col-sm-4">
                        <General general={generalInfo} />
                    </section>
                    /*End of left column*/

                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

And I do only have one copy of both react and react-dom.
The package.json also includes axios and react-router-dom as dependencies.

The IndexPage.js is used within the React Router in the App.js file.

```
<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={IndexPage} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Have anyone encountered this before?

Comment: How are you using `IndexPage` component?

Comment: I use the IndexPage component within the react router in App.js.

Comment: There are more details for debugging this issue on the official React site: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Yeah, I've been through that site 4 times already